# Pizzicato JS - No Frequency Data

Tags: javascript

I would like to use Pizzicato JS, with Three JS to create a sound visualizer. But for some reason after I get the frequency data, it's returning a frequency of 0 for each band. Is there something that I'm missing in order to get these frequencies so I can them manipulate my meshes with Three JS, please let me know?. I've attached a screenshot of my console window and pasted my code below for reference.

```
var context = Pizzicato.context;
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

var ambient = new Pizzicato.Sound('./mp3/ambient.mp3', playAmbient);
ambient.loop = true;
ambient.volume = 1;
ambient.connect(analyser);

var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
console.log("Frequency Data: " , frequencyData);
console.log("Frequency Data Length: " , frequencyData.length);`

function playAmbient(e)
{
    console.log("playAmbient();");
    ambient.play();
}
```

[image: CLICK HERE FOR SCREENSHOT!]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out, I was expecting the frequency data to return back a array of frequencies for each band when doing a console.log(). When in reality I had to receive my frequency data using the getByteFrequencyData method. I've pasted my new set of code to reference the issue of the undefined data.

```
context = Pizzicato.context;
analyser = context.createAnalyser();

sound = new Pizzicato.Sound(params, playAmbient);
sound.volume = 1;
sound.connect(analyser);

function playAmbient(e)
{
    console.log("playAmbient();");
    ambient.play();
}
setInterval(function () {
    try{
        var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
        frequencyData = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

        // The statement below was missing, and in return it will then 
        // update my frequencies for each band given from my 
        // frequencyData.
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);

        // Now I'm seeing the frequencies update in my console.log window 
        // when each interval is fired.
        console.log(frequencyData);
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }        
}, 500);
```